# how i can use same database for both PHP and Asp.net

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to do one project with PHP and Asp.Net. Database is MySql. How i can use the Same Database for both PHP and Asp.Net Website. Can i do that for this method. if i can means how i can use for the single database for both website. if i am passing values in the sense it will be store in a database from both PHP and Asp.Net Web Application.

I want to do one project with PHP and Asp.Net. Database is MySql. How i can use the Same Database for both PHP and Asp.Net Website. Can i do that for this method. if i can means how i can use for the single database for both website. if i am passing values in the sense it will be store in a database from both PHP and Asp.Net Web Application.

Comment: now i am using PHP web Application with Mysql. i need to develop 
Application in Asp.net with the same mysql. how i can do. in PHP i am using Phpmyadmin thats Why i am asking . please help me sir

Comment: Why are you opening another question ? You already opened a same thing earlier and you got some answers there. Try asking question in the same thread.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not proffered way.
to do so is as the following.

I suggest that you'll have 3 projects.

1. Php project (no database connection)
2. Asp.net project (no database connection)
3. API project (php / asp) - this project will get requests from the sites (1 and 2) and speak with the db

This situation is really recommended if both php and the asp.net sites are doing the same operations, even if 50% are the same, I recommend you'll do my recomendations